# Why my code not working merge multiple list into one

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a .csv file. I need to find the first column into a list.

```
IP
192.168.1.1,a
192.168.1.1,a
192.168.1.2,b
192.168.1.3,c
```

Code:

```
import csv

with open(r'C:\Users\windows\Desktop\file.csv', "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = [e[0].strip().split(",") for e in reader if e]
your_list[1:]
```

My output:

```
[['192.168.1.1'], ['192.168.1.1'], ['192.168.1.2'], ['192.168.1.3']]
```

My expected output:

```
['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3']
```

Comment: split returns a list. Should be `your_list = [e[0].strip().split(",")[0] for e in reader if e]`

Comment: You don't need the `.split()` part, as `csv` already does that for you.

You are getting lists because you are splitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv

your_list = []
with open(r'score.csv', "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = [ip[0] for ip in reader]

print(your_list[1:])
```

output:

```
['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3']
```